# When $Z$ is divided by $8$ the remainder is $5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $Z$ is divided by $8$ the remainder is $5$. What is the remainder when $4Z$ is divided by $8$?

My Attempt:

We know,
$$\textrm{dividend} =\textrm{divisor} \times \textrm{quotient} + \textrm{remainder}$$

$$Z=8\times k+5$$

$$Z-5=8K$$

$$\dfrac {Z-5}{8}=k$$

Now, what should I do further?

Comment: Have you tried an example or two?

Comment: Why not this?$$Z=8k+5\\4Z=4(8k+5)=32k+20=8(4k+2)+4$$

Comment: At first I thought this was a riddle. "When $\mathbb Z$ [the set of integers] is divided by $8$, the remainder is $5$. What is the remainder when $4\mathbb Z$ [the set of multiples of $4$] is divided by $8$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}Z&=8k+5\to \\4Z&=4(8k)+4\cdot 5\\&=8(4k)+20\\
&=8(4k)+16+4\\&=8(4k+2)+4\end{align}$$

So the remainder is $4$.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @Ramanujan: please take another look. Is it clear?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks! Much better now!

Comment: Yes sir. It is..